# Всегда ли суффикс указывает на частеречную принадлежность слова?

Tags: морфология

Eсли слово "потрясающий" (например, поступок) - это отглагольное прилагательное, почему у него суффикс причастия? Или это все-таки причастие?

Comment: Если вам дан хороший ответ, пожалуйста, не забудьте отметить его галочкой.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Потрясающий** ― это удивительный, поразительный, грандиозный и т.д. Слово сохранило  форму причастия (суффикс ЮЩ), но при этом  **перешло из причастия в прилагательное.**

Оно утратило признак по действию и приобрело качественный признак, о чем свидетельствует наличие синонимов среди прилагательных.

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

Примеры:

1) Прямое значение слова,  признак по действию, ***потрясающий*** ― **причастие**.

Ревущий ветер, **потрясающий** здания и производящий беспрестанный стук в окнах и дверях...

2) А в этом примере как бы обыгрывается двойное значение слова: ветер, ***потрясающий*** всё вокруг (причастие), и ветер ***потрясающий***, необыкновенный, удивительный (прилагательное).

Ветер вечный, ветер древний Между сопками ревёт. Рвёт траву и гнёт деревья И задиристо поёт! ... **Потрясающий** ветер!

Comment: То есть это прилагательное, т.к. утратило признак  по действию? Спасибо.